# Adobe Acrobat plugins

Tags: plugins, adobe, acrobat

I am building an Adobe Addin/plugin  (.api file ) and am faced with two problems
1) I have a cusotm tool that annotates the pdf with images. I want the image to show a tooltip with the author of that anotation when you hover on that image. Is this doabe

2) I am setting bookmarks.  When you look at the bookmarks in the bookmark pane how do you control the font and colour of the bookmark caption

any help greatly appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Take a look at function `AVDocSetSelection()` and the *SelectionServer* sample plugin in *Acrobat SDK*

2) The `/C` key in the XX controls the color of an Outline (bookmark) item. It's an array of three numbers [range 0.0 - 1.0] representing DeviceRGB color to be used for the outline entry’s text. Default value: [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]

The `/F` key controls whether the item is bold or plain styled.

You can not control the font.